# Compare child records in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about how to compare child record in an MS SQL database.
In my example I have 2 tables:

- `parent(Id int,name nvarchar(10))`
- `child(Id int, ParentId int(fk to parent.id),value1 nvarchar(10),value2 nvarchar(10),value3 nvarchar(10))`

Each parent record can have multiple child records and what I would like to know is which parent tables have child tables with the same values in `value1` and `value2`, where we ignore `value3`.

This I might be able to do by adding an additional field for the parent table, then loop though the child records and add the value of `value1` and `value2` to this additional field.

[start edit]
for instance I have the following data in the childtable
(id, parentid,val1,val2,val3
1,2,test1,test2,something
2,2,test0,test4,something
3,3,test1,test2,somethingelse
4,3,test0,test4,somethingelse
5,4,testx,test2,somethingelse
6,4,testx,test4,somethingelse

I would like to know that the records with parentID 2 and 3 have equal records for val1 and val2
[end edit]

I also would like to know is if 4 out of 5 childrecords have equal values or 3 out of 4.

I don't have a clue how to approach this at all, so I was hoping someone can help me. If my question isn't clear enough please let me know. Thank you for your answer and time.

Comment: Better than long text was a [MCVE - find details here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Take the work to write down some `DECLARE @parent TABLE(col1 ...)` statements with appropriate `INSERT INTO` statements and use the edit option to place this code for copy'n' paste. You'll get much better help! Just as a hint: No additional field and no loop is needed. Just read about `window function` `ROW_NUMBER` or `COUNT` with `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. But is this you looking for the `Group By` combination of `ParentId`, `value1` and `value2`? try: `Select ParentId, Value1, Value2, Count(*) From Child Group By ParentId, Value1, Value2 having Count(*) >1`

Answer (score 0):

If you have just to tables and dont want looping through all foreign keys. Then for first question:

```
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT parentID
FROM   
  childTable ct
WHERE  
  ISNULL(ct.value1, 0) = ISNULL(ct.value2, 0)
```

if you want see all field parent table

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT pt.*
FROM   
  childTable ct
    JOIN ParentTable pt
      ON pt.Id = ct.ParentID
WHERE  
  ISNULL(ct.value1, 0) = ISNULL(ct.value2, 0)
```

for second question:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM   
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(ct.id) countChildID,
      ct.ParentID
    FROM   
      childTable ct
    GROUP BY
      ct.ParentID
  ) S
    LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT 
             COUNT(ct.ID) countChildID,
             parentID
           FROM   
             childTable ct
           WHERE  
             ISNULL(ct.value1, 0) = ISNULL(ct.value2, 0)
           GROUP BY
             ParentID
         ) N
      ON S.ParentID = N.ParentId
WHERE S.countChildID = 5 AND N.countChildID = 3
```

for MS SQL server 2012 or higher you can use COUNT OVER(Partition BY)

Comment: thank you for your answer,
But I think I wasn't completely clear with my question. I'm not trying to compare the values of field 1 and 2 with each other, What I want to know is which parents have child record with simular values,

I will edit my post to describe this better.

for instance in the childtable I have the v

Answer (score 0):

You can count ParentId for each pair of value1 and c.value2 using **COUNT(p.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.value1, c.value2) AS equals_count**. After that you can count the number of all pairs:

```
CREATE TABLE #parent (
    Id INT
    ,NAME NVARCHAR(10)
    )

CREATE TABLE #child (
    Id INT
    ,ParentId INT
    ,value1 NVARCHAR(10)
    ,value2 NVARCHAR(10)
    ,value3 NVARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT INTO #parent
VALUES (
    1
    ,'first'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'second'
    ),(
    3
    ,'third'
    );

INSERT INTO #child
VALUES (
    1
    ,1
    ,'1'
    ,'1'
    ,'1'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,1
    ,'2'
    ,'2'
    ,'2'
    )
    ,(
    3
    ,1
    ,'1'
    ,'2'
    ,'3'
    )
    ,(
    4
    ,1
    ,'1'
    ,'3'
    ,'4'
    )
    ,(
    5
    ,2
    ,'1'
    ,'2'
    ,'5'
    )
    ,(
    6
    ,2
    ,'1'
    ,'3'
    ,'5'
    )
    ,(
    7
    ,3
    ,'1'
    ,'3'
    ,'5'
    );

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT p.Id AS ParentId
        ,p.NAME
        ,c.Id AS ChildId
        ,c.value1
        ,c.value2
        ,c.value3
        ,COUNT(p.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.value1, c.value2) AS equals_count
        ,COUNT(*) OVER() AS all_count
    FROM #parent AS p
    LEFT JOIN #child AS c ON p.Id = c.ParentId
    )
SELECT ParentId
        ,NAME
        ,ChildId
        ,value1
        ,value2
        ,value3
        ,equals_count
        ,all_count      
        ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte WHERE equals_count > 1  ) AS repeated_count
FROM cte
ORDER BY value1, value2

DROP TABLE #parent;

DROP TABLE #child;
```

Comment: please look ar [answer]. You should tell why your code solves the question